# Flutter: How to animate marker icon in google_maps_flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, flutter-animation, google-maps-flutter

I want to show pulse animated marker in `google_maps_flutter`.

**Is there any way to do like this(below) marker in Flutter?**

**I am able to do like this(below):**

> For easy to understand what I am able to achieve Please [check my
> github repository](https://github.com/Mahmud-CSE16/flutter_google_map) I described step by step.

**If there have any way to show animated marker in google_maps_flutter Please help me.

Thanks.**

Comment: Please, tell how you solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by adding circle on the same location as of markers and using animation controller to increase or decrease the radius of circle. I am able to achieve animation but it started lagging (different issues). You can refer to my question [Ripple animation from circles on google map flutter lags the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358791/ripple-animation-from-circles-on-google-map-flutter-lags-the-app) to get the animations done.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with that as well. Try this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker If you need some help implementing it, please let me know.

Comment: doesnt work with latest google_maps_flutter. It requires ^0.5.21 which is very old. Can you upgrade the plugin

Comment: Sure! Check it out again, no google maps dependencies

Comment: this lib is not so good for a production product.

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan what can I do to make animation smoother on google map referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358791/ripple-animation-using-circles-on-google-map-flutter-lags-the-app thank you.

Comment: I am still struggling to figure it out. I hope soon we will have a good marker animation library.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Avatar Glow Package](https://pub.dev/packages/avatar_glow) or if you may want to do it manually check the accepted answer on the below link
[Ripple animation flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611875/ripple-animation-flutter)