# Ripple animation using circles on google map flutter lags the app

Tags: flutter, google-maps, animation, geofencing, fluttermap

Following is the video that demonstrate the problem I am facing doing animations on google map.

[output of animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10qcm4q-TUfxrnwvRtEiXFSfkxoGCyCyW/view?usp=sharing)

I don't know why the app lags doing animations on google map specifically. I have also used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker but same result app lags is it the google plugins implementation that does'nt support animations or I'm doing the wrong way.

Following is the code that produces the issue.

```
class GoogleMapInteg extends StatefulWidget {
   const GoogleMapInteg({super.key});

  @override
  State<GoogleMapInteg> createState() => _GoogleMapIntegState();
}

class _GoogleMapIntegState extends State<GoogleMapInteg>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
 //* location initial
 final CameraPosition ciaro =
    const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(30.0455, 31.2360), zoom: 12.4746);

//* google map controller
late GoogleMapController? gmcontroller;

//* Initial delay
bool loading = true;
bool circleLoaded = false;
double radius = 1500; //* circle radius
AnimationController? animationController;
Set<Circle>? circles = {};

@override
void initState() {
  animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: (const Duration(milliseconds: 800)),
  )..repeat();

  _delay();
  super.initState();
}

//* initial delay
_delay() {
  //* delay before loading map
  Future.delayed(
    const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    () => setState(
      (() => loading = false),
    ),
  );
}

@override
void dispose() {
  //* dispose animations and map here
  animationController!.dispose();
  gmcontroller!.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: !loading
        ? Consumer<StationController>(
            //* [Station] consumer builder
            builder: (context, value, child) {
            return AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: animationController!,
              builder: (context, child) => GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: ciaro,
                zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                circles: value.stations
                  .map<Circle>(
                    (e) => Circle(
                      fillColor: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(
                          (animationController!.value - 1.0).abs()),
                      strokeColor: Colors.transparent,
                      strokeWidth: 1,
                      circleId: CircleId(e.name!),
                      visible: true,
                      center: e.location!,
                      radius: (radius * animationController!.value),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toSet(),
                markers: value.stations
                    .map<Marker>(
                    (Station element) => Marker(
                      markerId: MarkerId(element.name!),
                      position: element.location!,
                      consumeTapEvents: true,
                      icon: element.selected
                          ? element.iconNotSelected
                          : element.iconSelected,
                        onTap: () {
                          //* ADDING STATIONS TO PICKUP AND DESTINATION

                          value.addStation(element.name);
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                    .toSet(),

                //* ON MAP CREATED CONTROLLER

                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  //* setting map custom style for hinding labels

                  gmcontroller = controller;
                  gmcontroller!.setMapStyle(
                    jsonEncode(mapStyle),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          })
         //* PROGRESS INDICATOR
        : const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: kPrimaryColor,
              strokeWidth: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
     );
  }
}
```